# Сравнение двух файлов xml с помощью xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

Здравствуйте.

Есть два xml-файла. Структура у файлов одинаковая, один меньше другого. Необходимо сравнить файлы и получить элементы, которые есть в большом файле, но отсутствуют в маленьком.

Для поиска элементов, которые есть в обоих файлах, я использую такой код:

```
for $var1 in doc("path/to/big_file.xml")//PERSONS/PERSON
for $var2 in doc("path/to/small_file.xml")//PERSONS/PERSON
where $var1/ID = $var2/ID
return $var1
```

но для поиска различий он не работает. Ни `not($var1/ID = $var2/ID)`, ни тем более `$var1/ID != $var2/ID`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по Вашему примеру самый простой вариант такой:

```
let $small := doc("path/to/smal_file.xml")//PERSONS/PERSON
let $big := doc("path/to/big_file.xml")//PERSONS/PERSON

for $var1 in $big
where $pers[ ID != $small/ID ]
return 
  $var1
```

Пример с данными: https://gist.github.com/kontur32/af4ff8872b71eb5184e6ef3d94adc52d#file-_-_xml-xq